# Regex: ASCII codes (HTML format)

Tags: html, regex, ascii

What is the best regex to get all Unicode (ASCII) codes (HTML format)?

I need to extract XXX from &#XXX;

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex :

```
/&#\w+/u
```

But note that you need to specify the end of regex too for example if in your file the end of patters is `;` you can use

```
/&#\w+;/u
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following pattern: `/&#([^;]+)/g`

Comment: This will catch `&#^&^$$635&@$8%#^%#(#%;`. To only catch numbers, `/&#([0-9]+);/g` should work.